# (Capacity 20hr: 65AH) Does this mean 65amps per hour for up to 20 hours?

Tags: power, batteries, amperage, ampere-hour

Cranking Amps: 675
Im trying to find a good battery for a project.
That part where it says "20hr" keeps making me rethink what i sorta hope it means.

Comment: As you mention "cranking Amps" - note that lead batteries for cars are usually not suited to be charged and discharged many times. A battery with a high guaranteed cycle life might be better suited - e.g. batteries for storing energy in solar applications.

Comment: @asdfex: Actually, car batteries ARE designed to be discharged and recharged many, many times. What they are NOT designed for is deep discharges.

Comment: @DaveTweed - That's what I mean. But everything below 50% discharge can be considered deep and degrading lifetime while batteries designed for real discharge cycles can easily go to 30% and below. Starting a car takes roughly 1% of the total capacity of the battery and I wouldn't call this discharging but putting a brief but heavy load on the device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it means that you'll get a *total* of 65 amp-hours out of the battery when you discharge it over a 20-hour period. This would correspond to a current of

$$\frac{65 \text{ amp-hours}}{20 \text{ hours}} = 3.25 \text{ amps}$$

during the 20-hour discharge.

Battery capacity usually varies with the discharge rate (current), so for comparison purposes, a standard testing period is specified — in this case, 20 hours.

With higher currents (shorter periods), you'll measure less total capacity, since more energy is wasted in the battery's internal resistance. With lower currents, you'll measure somewhat higher capacity, up to some limit determined by the the construction of the battery.

Answer (score 3):

No that does not mean 65 Ampere for 20 hours.

What it means is that if you discharge this battery for a period of 20 houres, it will have a 65 AmpHour battery capacity. So you actually need to discharge it with 65 A / 20 hrs = 3.25 Ampere and then it will last 20 hours.

At a higher current batteries become less efficient and the amount of energy you can extract goes down. So 65 Ah usually does not mean that you get 65 Amps for 1 hour. You have to discharge at a modest rate so 10 or 20 hours is more reasonable and then you do get the specified capacity.

Answer (score 2):

65A per hour is written as 65A/h, not 65Ah.

That's Ampere-hour, or the product of time and current.

The 20 hour just means that you can take more energy out slowly. If you drain 65A it'll only last 30minutes, probably, because the higher the current, the lower the amount of energy you get out.

The 20 hour is just an indicator for how to get it out or in.